# Search to Determine if Key Value From One Table Never Matches Key Value From Another Table

Tags: sql-server

I am joining two tables (I'll refer to these as Table1 and Table3). A Key Value from Table1 (lets say compareValue1) is used in Table3 (albeit under a different name compareValue2).

With my database structure, compareValue1 does not have to match compareValue2.

What I am looking to do is write a Select query that takes compareValue1, looks through Table2, and shows me DataPoints where compareValue1 != compareValue2.

The queries I've tried thus far aren't capturing everything I need. For a given DataPoint compareValue1 != compareValue2 so when I look for that simple relation my query only excludes cases where compareValue1 = compareValue2.

Hopefully this makes sense, sorry if my explanation is not technical enough/confusing.

Update: I've recreated some data that better illustrates issue (and removed the old simplified version). Matthew's query doesn't appear to have done exactly what I'm looking. Additionally, I oversimplified my original query. In reality I need to join table1 to table2 so that I can join table3 and compare a value from table1 to table3.

```
    DECLARE @table1 as TABLE (Key1 INT, compareValue1 INT)

    DECLARE @table2 as TABLE (Key1 INT, Key2 varchar(5), compareValue1 INT, compareValue2 INT)

    DECLARE @table3 as TABLE (Key2 varchar(5), compareValue2 INT)

    INSERT INTO @table1 (Key1, compareValue1)
    VALUES (1, 1)
    ,      (1, 5)
    ,      (2, 7)
    ,      (3, 10)

    INSERT INTO @table2 (Key1, Key2, compareValue1, compareValue2)
    VALUES (1, 'a', 1, 1)
    ,      (1, 'a', 1, 3)
    ,      (1, 'a', 1, 12)
    ,      (1, 'a', 5, NULL)
    ,      (1, 'a', 5, 7)
    ,      (1, 'b', 5, 3)
    ,      (2, 'b', 7, 7)
    ,      (2, 'b', 7, 2)
    ,      (2, 'h', 7, 7)
    ,      (3, 'c', 10, 3)
    ,      (3, 'c', 10, NULL)
    ,      (3, 'd', 10, 6)
    ,      (3, 'b', 10, 11)

    INSERT INTO @table3 (Key2, compareValue2)
    VALUES ('a', 1)
    ,      ('a', 3)
    ,      ('a', 12)
    ,      ('a', NULL)
    ,      ('a', 7)
    ,      ('b', 3)
    ,      ('b', 7)
    ,      ('b', 2)
    ,      ('h', 7)
    ,      ('c', 3)
    ,      ('c', NULL)
    ,      ('d', 6)
    ,      ('b', 11)

    SELECT *
    FROM @table2 T2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @table1 T1
    ON T1.Key1 = T2.Key1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @table3 T3
    ON T3.Key2 = T2.Key2
```

Filtering on the necessary joins is where I encounter issues. What I'd like to see in my Select statement on table2 are the following data points.

```
    (1, 'a', 5, NULL)
    (1, 'a', 5, 7)
    (1, 'b', 5, 3)
    (3, 'c', 10, 3)
    (3, 'c', 10, NULL)
    (3, 'd', 10, 6)
    (3, 'b', 10, 11)
```

What do these all have in common? Taken as a group based on table1's data ([1,5] and [3,10]), compareValue1 never equals compareValue2.

```
    (1, 'a', 1, 1)
    (2, 'b', 7, 7)
    (2, 'h', 7, 7)
```

In that sense the above values would stop table1's data ([1,1] and [2,7]) from appearing in the results of my query because points exist where compareValue1 = compareValue2 EVEN THOUGH that's not always true. I.E. (1, 'a', 1, 3).

Thank you for taking the time to think this over.

Comment: Hi Indigo.  Welcome to S/O.  Yes this is a little confusing to be honest.  Can I suggest adding some sample data that can be cut and pasted? also expected output.  I think I may understand, but if you can make your question a little clearer, you'll find more people will help.  I'll post an example shortly.

Comment: Hi Indigo.  My apologies but I'm still having difficulties understanding the logic you require.  (1,1) seems to be included in table 1,2 & 3, but you were asking for a list of exclusions.  It may be worth giving us an idea on the real data behind this to help with our understanding.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I'll keep trying to expand on this but using the real data would take me a lot of time. I'd rather keep this in simplified terms if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @table1 AS TABLE (Key1 INT);

DECLARE @table2 AS TABLE (Key2 INT);

INSERT INTO @table1 (Key1)
VALUES (NULL)
,      (1)
,      (2)
,      (3);

INSERT INTO @table2 (Key2)
VALUES (NULL)
,      (1)
,      (2)
,      (3);

SELECT          *
  FROM          @table1 T1
 CROSS APPLY    @table2 T2
 WHERE          ISNULL(T1.Key1, -1) <> ISNULL(T2.Key2, -1)
 ORDER BY Key1
,         Key2;
```

Please note I've added two TVPs at the start and inserted data into them.  If you can provide a script like that with your question and suggested output, then it will make it much easier to help you in future.

If I've missed the mark then edit your question and make things easier to follow and we'll try to help.

Good luck.

Comment: Did my best to expand on the original question. The query you sent didn't accomplish what I was looking for. Hopefully, the edits to my original post help.

Comment: @IndigoGirls Explain how the query didn't accomplish what you were looking for.

Comment: As stated in my example I only want to retrieve instances where table1 is (1,5) and (3,10). The provided query did not isolate groups of data where compareValue1 NEVER EQUALS compareValue2. I was still seeing data for instances where table1 was (1,1) or (2,7).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer join` in any of its form.

- `left outer join` returns **all** records from left-side table and `null` from right side where there is no match.
- `right outer join` returns **all** records from right-side table and `null` from left side where there is no match.
- `full outer join` features both `left` and `right`.

  So the query may be like this.

  `select *
  from t1
  full outer join t2 on t1.key1 = t2.key2
  where t1.key1 is null or t2.key2 is null --select mismatches only`

Comment: Thanks for your input Alex, unfortunately it looks like this is only matching against NULL values, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Your thought to join the tables in a different manner is good though.

Comment: when I apply your query to my updated data (I had to make a couple of changes as I added another table to the mix) I'm not isolating the results I'm interested in.